# Override the __eq__ operator in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm working with declarative base SQLAlchemy. I'm in need of a string column that can be nulled but not have the NULL != NULL problem that comes along with databases. So I've written a custom "decorated" type based off of String that simply stores the sentry value "NONE" instead of a NULL so I can make it a not nullable row.

```
class NullableString(TypeDecorator):
     '''Turns None into the string "Null" and back in order to prevent Null!=Null issues'''
    impl = String
    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        return "NONE" if value is None else value
    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return None if value == "NONE" else value
```

The problem is that when I do a query on a column that is a NullableString type, I can't get results, ie:

```
  db_session.query(SomeModel).filter(SomeModel.nullable_col == None).all()
```

returns:

```
[]
```

but:

```
  db_session.query(SomeModel).filter(SomeModel.nullable_col == "NONE").all()
```

Returns several objects.

I've tried overwriting the `__eq__` operator in the `NullableString` class but still can't manage to make it work.

Comment: Please state your database backend.  The ORM is meant to abstract backend differences away but the None vs Null vs empty string problem has subtle differences in the backend implementation

Comment: Sorry, should have said MySQL, but in this case the backend is not important: I'm simply trying to make a backend agnostic solution to NULL not always equalling NULL

Answer (score 0):

Use [CustomComparators](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#building-custom-comparators) for override filter conditions.

Yours NullableString type is only "bind value/mapper"

Comment: This seems like the wrong solution, the comparison behavior should be captive inside my new type. Take the documentation example:  http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator you wouldn't ever be able to query for those values